# Order Of SQL query

Tags: sql

I want to find the order of the sql query.Which query is executed first. What will be the result of each intermediate set of query.

```
    select 0 from
(
select lg.a.aid ,lg.c.number from lg.a
left join lg.c
on lg.a.aid=lg.c.aid

)
as t1
where t1.number is null
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "first" or "second" thing that gets executed.

SQL is a *descriptive* language.  The SQL query describes the result set.  From a semantic perspective (understanding what the query means), there are rules that say "look at the `from` clause first, then the `where`, then the `group by`, and so on).  However, this only descries the parsing phase of the query.

What actually gets executed (in almost all SQL engines) is something called a directed-acyclic graph (DAG).  This represents a dataflow of components that do the processing.  The SQL compiler and optimizer create the DAG.  The relationship between the DAG and the original query is simple:  the results from the DAG should be what the query intends.

Your example is:

```
select 0
from (select lg.a.aid, lg.c.number
      from lg.a left join
           lg.c
           on lg.a.aid = lg.c.aid
     ) as t1
where t1.number is null;
```

It is not clear what you mean by your question:  "Which query is executed first?"  This example has only one query, albeit with a subquery.  In any reasonable way of processing the query, the logic for the subquery would need to be executed.  However, your query is equivalent to:

```
 select 0
 from lg.a left join
      lg.c
      on lg.a.aid = lg.c.aid
 where lg.number is null;
```

And that would have the same execution plan in most databases.